# Why doesn't this python regex work?

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a simple class that takes an input zip or postal code and either returns that value or zero-pads it out to five digits if it happens to be  all-numeric and less than 5 digits long.

Why doesn't my code work?

```
import re
class ZipOrPostalCode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.rawData = data
    def __repr__(self):
        if re.match(r"^\d{1,4}$", self.rawData):
            return self.rawData.format("%05d") 
        else:
            return self.rawData


if __name__ == "__main__":
    z=ZipOrPostalCode("2345")
    print(z)
```

The output I expect is 02345.  It outputs 2345.

Running it in the debugger, it is clear that the regular expression didn't match.

Comment: I think you misused the debugger, since the expression matches :) do like me (or Chuck Norris): I _never_ use python debuggers, I just stare at the code until it confesses.

Comment: Probably.  I couldn't make it recur.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Your regex works, it's the `format` that doesn't because you're trying to pass an integer format for a string, *and* the other way round, *and* with old-style `%` syntax...

In `str.format`, the string object bears the format (using `{}` style syntax) and the strings/integers/whatever objects to format are passed as *parameters*.

Replace (for instance) by:

```
if re.match(r"^\d{1,4}$", self.rawData):
    return "{:05}".format(int(self.rawData))
```

without format, you can also use `zfill` to left-pad with zeroes (faster, since you don't have to convert to integer)

```
return self.rawData.zfill(5)
```

and you probably don't even need to test the number of digits, just `zfill` no matter what or only if the zipcode is only digits:

```
def __repr__(self):
   return self.rawData.zfill(5) if self.rawData.isdigit() else self.rawData
```

Comment: Thank, I hadn't known about zfill()

Comment: it's little known, and usually not very useful since it only fills with zeroes. Just what you need, but that's a very special case!

Answer (score 3):

You've got your `format` code backwards.

```
return "{:05d}".format(int(self.rawData))
```